# Excel 2013 normal curve area not lining up

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a small excel sheet that I'm using to learn more about the value of normal random variables.  I created a graph with a normal curve (-30 to 30) with the appropriate formulas.

Column A: General Numbers -30 to 30 inclusive.
Column B: =NORMDIST(x,mean,standard_dev,FALSE)
Column C: =IF(Column A < X, Column B, "")

Column A and B work well, there's a normal curve all shaded in.

Column A and C however, doesn't line up vertically.

So.. if X = 0, the graph starts on x = 0, but then slants up and to the left... it doesn't go straight up.

[image: slantedArea]

I tried everything I could think of on this... Changed the cells to numbers instead of general.. changed the rounding..

The only difference between Column B and Column C is the formula used to get the number..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: What are the parameters?.....what is the exact equation in cell **B1**??

Comment: Column B: =NORMDIST(AI2, $X$16, $X$17, FALSE) where the cells reference Column A; the cell that holds the mean (100), and the cell that holds my standard deviation of 5.

Comment: We know what is in column **A**, what is in **B1**, etc.??

Comment: Column C: = IF(Column A < $Y$21, Column B, ""); where cell Y21 holds my x-variable (0)

Comment: If the *mean* is 100, why is the *x-range* {(-30)-(30)} ??

Comment: Since the area under the curve is always 1, the actual graph doesn't change, just the percentage of the 2nd graph (Column A & C).  You can change the mean to 0 and the standard deviation to 1.

Answer (score 0):

In **A1** I put *70*.  In **A2** I put `=A1 + 1` and copied down. In **B1** I put:

```
=NORMDIST(A16,100,5,FALSE)
```

and copied down.  In  **C1** I put:

```
=IF(A1<100,B1,"")
```

and copied down:

[image]

Note that **C** exactly matches **B**.  This is because **C** is not integrating **B**

To make **C** integrate **B**, in **C1** enter: `=B1` and in **C2** enter: `=C1 + B2`:

[image]

This is close to using the column **B** formula with the ***True*** parameter:

[image]